# Entity Framework: "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" error without Lazy Loading

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

There is a stored procedure that we use to export some data from our DB. We pass the list of IDs and it returns the according records. Normally there are 2 millions of IDs to pass to the SP and in order to reduce the load we break the IDs down to batches. Each batch has 2000 Ids.

Then we make calls to that SQL Server stored procedure in a loop and each time the loop runs, 5 concurrent threads pass their IDs (2000 IDs each) etc. This used to work perfectly but recently it has started breaking down at some point by returning this error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

I have increased the CommandTimeOut property of the DbContext to int.Max, and I have disabled LazyLoading (plus I am calling .ToList to make sure collections are fetched). Things got a bit better after making these changes but still the operation fails after exporting 1,400,000 records (out of 2 million).

Here is the code that is run by concurrent threads:

```
public List<ExportedData> GetDownloads(IEnumerable<int> downloadIds)
    {
        var results = new List<ExportedData>();

        using (var dbc = new DefaultEntities())
        {
            dbc.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeOut;
            dbc.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            results.AddRange(dbc.ExportDownloads(string.Join(";", downloadIds), true).ToList());
            dbc.Connection.Close();
        }

        return results;
    }
```

What can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: How big are the IDs being passed in?

Comment: And what is the datatype of the parameter passed in to the SP?

Comment: What do you mean by "How Big", @DavidG ? IDs are integer numbers and each time we pass a list of 2000 IDs. As seen in the code above the parameter is a ; separated list of Ids. The second parameter is not used really.

Comment: I'm trying to get a feel for how large a string you are passing into the procedure sp `1;2;3` is different from `12345678;12345679;12345680`

Comment: @DavidG I got it now :-) Each ID is pretty much a 5-digit integer value.

Comment: And the string parameter for the stored procedure, it's a VARCHAR of some sort?

Comment: VARCHAR(1)? VARCHAR(2)? Maybe VARCHAR(3)? This is hard work!

Comment: I have no idea. I do not have the source of that stored procedure.

Comment: So you haven't taken a look inside it to see what it might be doing with those 2000 IDs? I'd start there before doing anything else.

Comment: I have asked the person who has created this SP and works for another company to look into the SP. The SP extracts the IDs and runs a simple select statement. I checked the Model Browser and apparently the type of input parameter is varchar(max) but not sure how this might be related to the cause of the issue?!